# MSBuild: Conditional Construct (Project Reference | File Reference)

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, msbuild, reference, cobol

I´m still trying to eleminate the need of a cobol compiler in a Project with cobol-Projects in it.

Is it possible to create following build behaviour:

If the Configuration is Debug then use ProjectReferences on ExCobol.cblproj
if the Configuration is DebugVB then use FileReferences on ExCobol.dll

When Yes, How to achieve it?

I assume the use of  tags in the project file will 
do the trick.

And does this really eliminate the need of a cobol compiler for the
DebugVB Configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the conditional 'how', assuming you have either

```
<ProjectReference ...>...</ProjectReference>
```

or

```
<Reference ...>...</Reference>
```

you want to hand-edit the .proj file to include both thusly

```
<ProjectReference Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='DebugVB'" ...>...</ProjectReference>
<Reference Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DebugVB'" ...>...</Reference>
```

Comment: At least a part of the question answered.
Guess I have to try the rest by myself.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Coming late to the party, but I find myself doing something similar, and from a straight MSBuild perspective, this works great. Compiles correctly based on the build-configuration.  However, I've experienced some weirdness in VS2010 - for example, the references in project explorer always look like the assembly-references.  Also, Build-Order isn't figured out automatically.  I'm assuming that's because of VS seeming to think, even if conditionals stipulate ProjectReference, it's an assembly Reference.

Comment: @Yoopergeek - I'm experiencing the Assembly vs Project Reference, too.  Were you able to resolve it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738246/buildinginsidevisualstudio-property-value-not-working-with-file-reference-and-pr

Answer (score 0):

Almost forgot this question:
the answer from Brian works perfectly for me.

And to answer the second part of the question:

It indeed eliminates the need for a cobol compiler on every maschine if you
setup different Configurations.

Thanks Brian.